# How Upload large files to Onedrive using PHP-Curl

Tags: php, api, curl, onedrive

I need to upload file size grater than 4MB to onedrive account. I am trying with PHP and curl for this. Is anyone tried for this option, Please help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: you have not told us the problem, or shared any code???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$url='https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/filename:/createUploadSession';

```
    $data= '{}';
    $header = array('Content-Type: json',
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Pragma: no-cache",
        "Authorization: bearer {Access Token}");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```

get the uploadURL from the result,

```
    $graph_url = $result['uploadUrl'];
    $fragSize = 320 * 1024;
    $file = file_get_contents($filename_location);
    $fileSize = strlen($file);
    $numFragments = ceil($fileSize / $fragSize);
    $bytesRemaining = $fileSize;
    $i = 0;
    $ch = curl_init($graph_url);
    while ($i < $numFragments) {
        $chunkSize = $numBytes = $fragSize;
        $start = $i * $fragSize;
        $end = $i * $fragSize + $chunkSize - 1;
        $offset = $i * $fragSize;
        if ($bytesRemaining < $chunkSize) {
            $chunkSize = $numBytes = $bytesRemaining;
            $end = $fileSize - 1;
        }
        if ($stream = fopen($filename_location, 'r')) {
            // get contents using offset
            $data = stream_get_contents($stream, $chunkSize, $offset);
            fclose($stream);
        }

        $content_range = " bytes " . $start . "-" . $end . "/" . $fileSize;
        $headers = array(
            "Content-Length: $numBytes",
            "Content-Range:$content_range"
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graph_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, constant('CURL_SSL_VERIFYPEER_STATUS'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

        $bytesRemaining = $bytesRemaining - $chunkSize;
        $i++;
    }
```

And when you passing the last set of data it should be the correct data bytes. Otherwise it will fail the upload session.

Answer (score 3):

Your application needs to:

- Create an upload session
- Upload bytes to the upload session

Refer to the OneDrive Dev Center's Upload large files with an upload session documentation page here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession#create-an-upload-session for details as to the type of requests to make for each step and what JSON or http response codes to expect.

From a PHP functionality standpoint, you'd want to:

1. determine the attributes of the file for your upload (file size, file name)
2. Send post data via curl to create upload session (See section entitled [***SEND POST FROM CURL*** in this blog post](https://www.madebymagnitude.com/blog/sending-post-data-from-php/) for an example code snippet for #1.)
3. parse the uploadUrl from the JSON response to above into a php variable
4. Send the binary contents via cURL to the uploadURL extracted above (See section entitled [***Send the binary contents via cURL*** in this blog post](https://ryansechrest.com/2012/07/send-and-receive-binary-files-using-php-and-curl/) (either send whole file, or in partial chunks- size of file and connection/bandwidth should be taken into consideration to determine approach)
5. parse the response header (http response code) and conditionally:

   - retry with expected byte range if it failed (response code of HTTP 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable)
   - continue with next byte range if transmitting byte ranges/partials (response code of `202 Accepted`) - refer to "Resuming an in-progress upload"
   - complete/return/exit out of functionality (response code of `HTTP 200 OK` or `HTTP 201 Created`)
   - on any 50x responses, send a GET request (refer to "Resuming an in-progress upload") to determine what to send next/how to resume

In the case of a filename conflict being detected (response code of `HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict`):

1. [Send a DELETE request using curl command](https://www.garron.me/en/bits/curl-delete-request.html) to cancel the upload session (you should get a response code of `HTTP/1.1 204 No Content`.
2. Resolve/handle the name conflict
3. Restart the process

Answer (score 1):

this code is working for me :

```
<?php

$fileName="myfile.zip";
$filename_location=realpath($fileName);

$token="{access token}";
$ch = curl_init();
$url="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/api/$fileName:/createUploadSession";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
$data= '{
    "item": {
        "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename",
        "description": "description",
        "fileSystemInfo": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.fileSystemInfo" },
        "name": "'.$fileName.'"
  }
}';
    $header = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Pragma: no-cache",
        "Authorization: bearer $token");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch)) ;


$graph_url = $result->uploadUrl;


    $fragSize = 320 * 1024;
    $file = file_get_contents($filename_location);
    $fileSize = strlen($file);
    $numFragments = ceil($fileSize / $fragSize);
    $bytesRemaining = $fileSize;
    $i = 0;
    $ch = curl_init($graph_url);
    while ($i < $numFragments) {
        $chunkSize = $numBytes = $fragSize;
        $start = $i * $fragSize;
        $end = $i * $fragSize + $chunkSize - 1;
        $offset = $i * $fragSize;
        if ($bytesRemaining < $chunkSize) {
            $chunkSize = $numBytes = $bytesRemaining;
            $end = $fileSize - 1;
        }
        if ($stream = fopen($filename_location, 'r')) {
            // get contents using offset
            $data = stream_get_contents($stream, $chunkSize, $offset);
            fclose($stream);
        }

        $content_range = " bytes " . $start . "-" . $end . "/" . $fileSize;
        $headers = array(
            "Content-Length: $numBytes",
            "Content-Range:$content_range"
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graph_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $bytesRemaining = $bytesRemaining - $chunkSize;
        $i++;
    }

?>
```